# How to expand to another island?

Tags: way-of-gold-and-steel

I cannot figure out how to do it. How to expand to an other island?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After building your shipyard, build a ship and move to another island.

Then instead of going ashore there is a red option that says 'Disassemble ship and start a new colony' or something like that. Select that and you're done.